# What web applications are available for mindmapping?

Tags: webapp-rec

Relevant additional information would be features, offline usage, mobile integration and pricing.

Comment: [Mind42.com](http://www.mind42.com) is a collaborative mindmapping webapp. It appears to be free.

Answer (score 14):

[Mindmeister](http://www.mindmeister.com/).

It's a good one, the best part is that you can use OpenID to sign in, so there is no need to register yet another account.

Comment: Nice thing! Are there any export options available?

Comment: @Aaron, if I'm not mistaken there is, but I am not sure.

Comment: In the free version, there are only export options to MindMeister format (`.mind`), PDF and RTF. However, you can also [export to Markdown and FreeMind](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/154358) with a trick, and from FreeMind to other formats.

Answer (score 4):

There is a new webapp currently in beta called [Popplet](http://popplet.com/).  They have a [preview video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DU5q7ms4LfI) if you want to see what the software can do, and they already have an iPad app to play with too.

Couple of explaining images grabbed from their home page:

[image: Record Thoughts]
<sub>(source: [popplet.com](http://popplet.com/images/whatis/03.png))</sub>
[image: Collect Inspiration]
<sub>(source: [popplet.com](http://popplet.com/images/whatis/01.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

[Prezi](http://prezi.com/) is more suitable for presentation rather than creation of mind maps but is definitely worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

#### ThoughtMuse

http://www.thoughtmuse.com/

I haven't spent a lot of time playing with this one, but it looks interesting.
If anyone has a look, please leave a comment saying how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't yet been able to try this but I noticed [Google Docs](http://dogs.google.com/) has recently added support for drawings. This might prove to be great for mindmapping.

Comment: Trying to do mind maps in google docs drawings (a very painful experience) was the thing that prompted us to write our own collaborative mind mapping inspired by what we should google *should* have implemented!

Answer (score 0):

Two nice **webapps for mindmapping** that haven't been suggested yet are:

- www.lovelycharts.com/
- www.mindomo.com/

Their mobile integration and offline usage doesn't appear to be fantastic - you might be better off with www.mindmeister.com for that, but it is always good to have more options.

**Pricing for Lovely Charts**

[http://imgur.com/tvPOc.png](https://imgur.com/tvPOc.png)

The pricing converts to **~US$22.60 for Professional, and ~$36.50 for gold.**

**Pricing for Mindomo**

www.mindomo.com/pricing.htm

Answer (score 0):

There's a list here http://www.mind-mapping.org/web-based-mindmappers/ with several pages of details and compatibility info

Regards

Vic Gee  (@VicGee on Twitter)

Mind-Mapping.Org

The master list of mind mapping & 
information management software

Answer (score 0):

I use Seavus DropMind™ an excellent web and desktop mind mapping software with a lot of functionalities which can facilitate your everyday thinking process. It is great mind mapping tool for brainstorming, planning, organizing and sharing ideas in real time.

Answer (score 0):

[ThinkBuzan](http://www.thinkbuzan.com) are launching an online Flash version of their mind mapping software, I believe next month in April.

Answer (score 0):

### [Coggle](http://coggle.it)

Coggle is by far the most elegant, it's free, and it packs some serious features too:

- supports Markdown *and* LaTeX syntax for links, text formatting, and math
- view the revision history
- drag-drop to add images
- real-time collaborative editing
- pdf export (as vectors)
- touch-based user interface on iOS

<sub>I'm one of the Coggle team, so you'd think I was being biased, but I'd say to try it and see...</sub>