# How to export from the MindMeister web app to FreeMind format?

Tags: mindmeister

I used the [MindMeister](https://www.mindmeister.com/) browser-based collaborative mindmapping tool to create a mindmap. Now I want to export it to [FreeMind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) format, as FreeMind is my default open source mindmapping tool for offline use.

How can I do that export?

Answer (score 0):

You ave three options:

- **Quick free option.** Here we exploit the fact that MindMeister provides a Markdown formatted outline as a clipboard format, and that this is very similar to a clipboard format that FreeMind accepts for import.

  1. Select the root node of your mindmap and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy it to the clipboard.
  2. Insert the clipboard content into a text editor.
  3. Remove all occurrences of "`-` " from the start of lines. These are used as the bullet character in the MindMeister clipboard format. But keep the indentation with four spaces per mindmap level in place.
  4. Copy your text editor content.
  5. Paste your clipboard content into a FreeMind mindmap. This will result in a logical structure of nodes below the currently selected one, corresponding to the nested list structure you saw in the text editor. Because when pasting plain text into FreeMind, it will interpret multiples of spaces at the start of a line to mean an indentation level of a nested list.
  6. You may have to do some manual cleanup, as all formatting that was potentially present in the MindMeister mindmap and visible as Markdown markup in your text editor will now still be visible as Markdown source code in FreeMind nodes.
- **Better free option.** Export to MindMeister format (`.mind`) from the MindMeister web app, then use the Go script [mind2mm](https://github.com/p2c2e/mindmeister-to-freemind) developed by Sudharsan Rangarajan ([details](https://www.diyd2.in/articles/freemind-mindmeister/)).
- **Paid option.** In the right bottom of the MindMeister web application, click the "Export" icon, then export to FreeMind format from the dialog. This requires a paid subscription ("Personal" plan or higher).